# jstree get_json returns false

Tags: jquery, jstree

I'm using jsTree plugin to display tree.
The tree is loaded using ajax to a div with ul-li structure. And here is how I initialize it.

```
$("#jseq_tree").jstree({
      "core" : { "check_callback" : true},
      "plugins" : ["dnd","wholerow"]
}).jstree("open_all");
```

I'm trying to get all nodes from the tree on a button click like that:

```
$(document).on("click", "#sub_tree", function() {
    var v =$('#jseq_tree').jstree('get_json', -1);
    var mytext = JSON.stringify(v);
    alert(mytext);
});
```

But it always alerts false. How can I make it work? Or how can I get all elements of the tree with their ids and children?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found solution:

```
var v =$("#jseq_tree").jstree(true).get_json('#', { 'flat': true });
```